# Как получить и управлять toolbar'ом из Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Fragment должен содержать toolbar, tabview и viewpager.
toolbar из библиотеки android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.

Activity, в которую подгружается фрагмент, содержит только FrameLayout.

Подскажите, как правильно получить toolbar и настроить его в классе фрагмента?

Comment: В разметку фрагмента поместите Toolbar, потом к нему обращайтесь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте ToolBar в активити.

http://javatechig.com/android/android-lollipop-toolbar-example

Чтобы получить доступ к нему из фрагмента - getActivity().getSupportActionBar();

Comment: А нельзя сделать так, чтобы разметка ToolBar'a была только в layoute'e фрагмента, и потом этот фрагмент подгрузить в Activity, которое содержит только FrameLayout, ну и, соответственно, потом настроить ToolBar как надо? Просто дело в том, что мне нужно подгружать несколько фрагментов и в каждом случае различается ToolBar.

Comment: Попробуйте создать тулбар как написано в уроке, но не в активити, а прямо в фрагменте, затем его установить для активити - getActivity().setSupportActionBar();

Comment: спасибо, все получилось)

Comment: Только теперь ActionBarDrawerToggle пропала(

Comment: как вы устанавливали `ActionBarDrawerToggle` на `ActionBar`?

Comment: Если вам помогло решение, отметьте его галочкой, так другим людям с подобной проблемой будет легче найти правильный ответ.

Comment: Activity, в которую подгружается фрагмент с Toolbar'ом, содержит NavigationVIew, и ActionBarDrawerToggle устанавливаю когда инициализирую DrawerLayout:                                      ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, navigationDrawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        navigationDrawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

Comment: не уверен, но может попробовать сделать то же самое прямо в фрагменте? чтобы получить доступ к вью из активити и инициализировать их в фрагменте, можно воспользоваться методом getActivity().findViewById();

Comment: да, действительно, спасибо)

Comment: Рад был помочь:))